# git: fatal: '--ours/--theirs' cannot be used with switching branches

Tags: git, git-merge

In a merge conflict, I'm trying to resolve all the merge conflicts in favour of a particular branch.

I'm trying to do `git checkout --ours`, but I get the following error:

```
fatal: '--ours/--theirs' cannot be used with switching branches
```

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 34):

Using `git checkout` with `--ours` or `--theirs` expects at least one argument: the path(s) of the files / directories to checkout.

As [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---ours) says:

> When checking out paths from the index, check out stage #2 (ours) or #3 (theirs) for unmerged paths.

So:

```
git checkout --ours <path(s)>
```

Comment: Interestingly, in an incognito browser, Google has only seen this whole error string a single time: in a comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28782831/5353461). Without the `fatal` preamble it turns up an extra 5 times. Why isn't it picking up the string in the source code I wonder?

Comment: Because it's not a single string: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/checkout.c#L1085-L1086

Comment: git checkout --ours <path> won't work with the branch name. The question is how to switch to a branch with automatically resolving merge conflicts with --ours strategy